# Join tables fetching column name and sum issue

Tags: sql, join

I'm stuck with one query where I'm storing column names of table B in table A and trying to fetch column_name and sum(column_name) from tables A and B

```
SELECT 
metric AS attribute,
SUM(metric) AS total
FROM x_instr ase
JOIN
(SELECT sites.id AS site_id, sites.name AS sitename,
    a.metric_name AS metric
FROM
    sites, servers, x_y_aiminstr_attrnames a, x_instr b
WHERE
    a.mbeanid = b.mbeanid  
    AND sites.id = b.siteid
    AND b.time BETWEEN '2018-02-09 00:00:00' AND '2018-02-09 23:59:59'
    AND b.serverid = servers.id
    AND sites.name = 'x_y_z_1'
GROUP BY metric) subquery 
ON ase.siteid = subquery.site_id
GROUP BY attribute
```

The result set returns zero even there are values present. What i mean to do in short is that i'm trying to pull column name along with its aggregate sum from 2 tables

Comment: Your query is technically invalid because you are doing `GROUP BY metric` but then doing things like selecting `sites.id`.  I would guess that you're using MySQL.  To your actual question, you could try doing a left join between `x_instr` and the subquery.  That might retain records which you expect, but are currently being filtered off.

Comment: @user3414559. Is your inner query is fetching the results ?

Comment: Please post the sample data and expected result also. That would help us better to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this If your inner query gives you the results

```
SELECT 
metric AS attribute,
SUM(metric) AS total
FROM x_instr ase
JOIN
(SELECT sites.id AS site_id, sites.name AS sitename,
    a.metric_name AS metric
FROM
    sites, servers, x_y_aiminstr_attrnames a, x_instr b
WHERE
    a.mbeanid = b.mbeanid  
    AND sites.id = b.siteid
    AND b.time BETWEEN '2018-02-09 00:00:00' AND '2018-02-09 23:59:59'
    AND b.serverid = servers.id
    AND sites.name = 'x_y_z_1') subquery 
ON ase.siteid = subquery.site_id
GROUP BY attribute
```